# Why am I getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

GridView1I am trying to switch my code on gridview from this:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsPar" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connstring %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT ID,  FileNumber, address, phone from myTable ORDER BY ID"  FilterExpression="ID like '%{0}%'">
        <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="StreetSrch" ControlID="searchBox" PropertyName="Text" />
        </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

to this:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT ID,  FileNumber, address, Phone from MyTable WHERE Id LIKE '%@strSearch%'  ORDER BY Id"

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
        Dim dt As DataTable = GetData(cmd)
        Dim CheckBoxArray As ArrayList
        If ViewState("CheckBoxArray") IsNot Nothing Then
            CheckBoxArray = DirectCast(ViewState("CheckBoxArray"), ArrayList)
        Else
            CheckBoxArray = New ArrayList()
        End If

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Gridview1.DataBind()
            Dim CheckBoxIndex As Integer
            Dim CheckAllWasChecked As Boolean = False
            Dim chkAll As CheckBox = DirectCast(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).FindControl("chkAll"), CheckBox)
rest of code....
End If
End Sub
```

Finally, below is a snapshot of the markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"
                OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" HeaderStyle-CssClass = "header" Font-Size = "10pt" 
                 AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" OnRowDataBound = "RowDataBound" AllowSorting="true" 
                 PageSize="20" CssClass="Gridview" 
                 GridLines="None">
```

I am getting `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` on the following line:

Line 44:             Dim chkAll As CheckBox = DirectCast(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).FindControl("chkAll"), CheckBox)

Any idea how to resolve this?

Code is very long and I didn't want to post all of it here. I can post more if needed.

Comment: you need to fix your formatting, you should be able to see it's pretty unreadable and you've got a load of unformatted stuff in the middle. Also you've got `Dim strQuery As String = "Line 44: ` which doesn't look quite right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT is throwing a null reference exception because

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).FindControl("chkAll")
```

doesn't find a checkbox so it returns null (Nothing) so what you are essentially doing is trying to cast Nothing to a checkbox.

Comment: it is funny you said that. Each checkbox has a value and infact, before changing from SELECTCommand to codebehind, there was no problem. All, I thank you very much for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try dimming as a New instance of an object, this may be causing your issue? When i get this particular exception its usually because I Dim something without the 'New'

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Break in the debugger on that line.  Then you can use the Quick Watch feature to look at parts of the line to see what is null.  Start by looking at GridView1.  If that isn't null, look at GridView1.HeaderRow.  Continue until you find the null object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a breakpoint and the watch window to find out where exactly your code went wrong. The `NullReferenceException` is thrown whenever you try to invoke a method on a variable that is `Nothing`.

Code example with Option Infer On:

```
Dim firstHeaderCell = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0)
Debug.Assert(firstHeaderCell IsNot Nothing, "Couldn't find the first header cell")
Dim chkAllControl = firstHeaderCell.FindControl("chkAll")
Debug.Assert(chkAllControl IsNot Nothing, "Couldn't find a control named chkAll")
Dim chkAll As CheckBox = TryCast(chkAllControl, CheckBox)
Debug.Assert(chkAll IsNot Nothing, "chkAll exists but it isn't a CheckBox")
```

Those assertions are totally overkill, but one can't give a code example with "breakpoints" and "watch window"-variables.

Comment: You'll need to import the namespace: `Import System.Diagnostics`. Or have the IDE do it for you by pressing CTRL+ALT+F10 while the cursor is on "Debug".

Comment: I added it directly to the code like: System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(...)

Now, I get:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on this line:

Dim firstHeaderCell = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0)

I was hoping this would be a quick fix.

Comment: It looks like you either don't have a Header (ie `GridView1.HeaderRow Is Nothing`) or your HeaderRow doesn't have Cells (ie `GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0) Is Nothing`)
I would guess you don't have a headerrow as Cells(0) would probably throw a `OutOfRangeException`.

I assume you are pretty new to OO programming as this is a pretty straightforward Exception. You can read a bit more about NullReferenceExceptions [here](http://rainstorms.me.uk/blog/2009/11/08/exceptions-explained-nullreferenceexception/).

Comment: Just a heads up: A `NullReferenceException` occurs when you invoke a method or property on a variable that is `null` in C#. In VB.NET this happens when you call a method on a variable that is `Nothing`. As far as NullReferenceExceptions go, null and Nothing are the same thing.

Comment: No, I do have Gridview1.HeaderRow. As stated, this was working fine when I was using SelectCommand="Select Id, ...

This issue started when I wanted to do the SELECT in codebehind with filter.

I am actually following example I found here:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Preserving-state-of-Checkboxes-while-paging-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control.aspx

It is pretty straight forward, except I am trying to integrate it into my working code.

Comment: Guess: When the page loads, you execute a query that returns zero rows, the GridView doesn't render and you don't have a headerrow. As said before, I would put a breakpoint (F9) and check everything for `Nothing` in the immediate, locals or watch window.